# Neo4j Dump: How to specify the database?

Tags: neo4j, export, dump

Having successfully created and populated a database with 200,000+ nodes, I would like to create a dump as a backup.
The instructions in the documentation are simple:

```
neo4j-admin dump --database=<database> --to=<destination-path>
```

But it's not clear what to use for `<database>`. If I use `graph.db` (or leave out the option) I get an error. I know the location of the database folder.

If I put the path to the database I get the following error:

```
unexpected error: 'database' should be a name but you seem to have specified a path
```

OS: Windows 10

Comment: did you try "graph" ?  (without quotation marks)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

The `database` parameter refers to databases that are located in *neo4jFolder*/data/databases folder, where *neo4jFolder* is the folder of the unzipped install of Neo4j. 
For example: I unzipped the neo4j install zip into `E:\Program Files\neo4j-community-3.3.2`. My database was elsewhere on the drive. So I copied the database to `E:\Program Files\neo4j-community-3.3.2\data\databases\MyDatabase`. Then I was able to run `neo4j-admin dump --database=MyDatabase --to=backup5.dmp` successfully.

I don't know if it's possible to run **dump** on databases that are not found under `/data/databases`. I also don't know how to run a dump when Neo4j is installed with the **exe** installer. My solution is for the **zip** file installation.